# Emailing Distribution List owners from a imported .csv file of Distribution list

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv, html-email, exchange-server

I am having issues with a script I have been working on in Powershell that emails the distribution list Owners from an imported .csv of distribution list...

Here is the script:

```
$email=Get-DistributionGroup  (ipcsv c:\Scripts\TestEmailList.csv).DisplayName | select PrimarySmtpAddress, @{n= "Owner"; e={$_.ManagedBy | foreach {(Get-Mailbox $_).PrimarySMTPAddress}}},@{n= "name"; e={$_.name | foreach {(Get-Mailbox $_).displayname}}}

$GroupNames = import-csv c:\Scripts\TestEmailList.csv | Foreach {Get-DistributionGroup -Identity $_.DisplayName | Select Primarysmtpaddress} 

$PSEmailServer = "smtp.consoco.com"

$body="<html><body>Hello $($Email.owner), The Email Admins are in the process of auditing distribution groups, and you have been identified as the owner of the group <b>$($GroupNames.Primarysmtpaddress)</b>. This group was flagged as being inactive. <p>This Distribution list will be restricted for 60 days then deleted.</body></html>"  

   $parameters = @{
    From = 'emailadmins@consoco.com'
    To = $email.owner
    Subject = 'Attention Distribution List Owner'
    Body = $body
    BodyAsHTML = $true
    BCC = 'me@consoco.com'
    Priority = 'High'
    
}
Send-MailMessage @parameters -SmtpServer $PSEmailServer
```

Here is the error message that I receive:

```
Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert the "System.Collections.ArrayList" value of type "System.Collections.ArrayList" to type
"Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.DistributionGroupIdParameter".
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-DistributionGroup], ParameterBindin...mationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Get-DistributionGroup
    + PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com
```

I believe that the error message is calling for me to make an Array, but I am having trouble with creating one in the script.

If anyone can help, it would be greatly appreciated!....Thanks

Comment: Is your `(ipcsv ...).DisplayName` is returning a string? The error makes it sound like it is an array while Get-DistributionGroup takes a string as an argument.

Comment: when I run the .csv with just one distribution list in it, the script works perfectly...but when I add more than 1 distribution list to the .csv file, I get that error message.

Comment: So loop through the content my guy. `$content = import-csv $path` and then `foreach ($distro in $content)`. (do this with one row in the csv and then multiple rows) assign your input statement to a variable instead of pipelining it and output the variable. notice how it is a different data type? you can use $var.gettype() to see the actual type too